# Using ActionMailer in Rails to receive emails from forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to receive emails from a Contact Form using ActionMailer in Rails 5. But I am not sure on how send the params of the resource created on the form to the email on the receive method and send it to the email of the app.

controllers/contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      DefaultMailer.receive(@contact).deliver
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :body)
  end
end
```

mailers/default_mailer.rb:

```
class DefaultMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "atendimento@lcasystems.com.br"

  def receive(email)
    mail.create(subject: email.subject, body: email.body)
  end
end
```

It gives a 500 server error and  says undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass in the receiver method.

Answer (score 1):

It's a contact form, so you want the email to be sent to yourself, so you need the `to:` key-value pair.

It's also useful to include the contact's name and email so you can know where to send any replies.

```
def receive(contact)
  mail(to: "atendimento@lcasystems.com.br", 
       subject: contact.subject, 
       body: contact.body.to_s + 
            "\n (Sender is #{contact.name} and their email is #{contact.email})")
end
```